# Displaying individual element of objects in arraylist on combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an object with 2 element fields for C#, and I have inserted them into an arraylist. I am trying to get them to display on the combobox.

This is what I currently have

```
ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();
mylist.Add(new myobject("name1", "value1"));
mylist.Add(new myobject("name2", "value2"))
mylist.Add(new myobject("name3", "value3"));

ComboBox1.ItemsSource = drinksArray;
```

The following code would just display 3 elements which are "ClassName.myobject" for my combobox.

I am trying to get it to display "name1", "name2" and "name3".

I have a getName() method for my object but I do not know how to implement it into the combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Call the `getName()` method in the `ToString()` method of the `myobject` class:

```
public class myobject
{
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

Or set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the name of a *public property* of the `myobject` class that returns the value you want to display as suggested by @zambonee:

```
ComboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a readonly property to your `myobject` class that returns `getName()`, then set `DisplayMemberPath` on the `ComboBox` to the name of that property.

If the name can ever change, you will want to implement `INotifyPropertyChange` and raise its event for the property whenever the value should be updated.